# Should I use a fixed navigation in a one-page site to improve usability?

Tags: usability

Client wants a single page website with a lot of stuff to show. I have no images to show, only text and maybe a couple videos.

This is a first version I've been working on:

[image]

Ok, so my question is: Should I use a fixed navigation in a one-page site to improve usability?

The page is too long and I'm afraid users might feel lost if they decide to scroll down. Is a fixed menu a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: welcome to UX.SE. In order to provide you with an answer, could you please provide more details, preferably a mockup or wireframe? Right now your question is too broad and very difficult if not impossible to answer

Comment: Thanks! And yeah of course, sorry about that. I'll edit the question in a second;

Comment: if you decide to go with a sticky header, be sure to kill the excess of padding on top of the menu or it will cover a big part of your content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply not really. Sticky header code slows down applications, reduces the smoothness of animations and often just get in the way.

Sticky headers don't offer much functionality, your content is what should be leading the user in and out of pages not a navigation. A navigation is mainly for jumping to something you already know you are after otherwise you progress through the page naturally.

Take a look at the goal you want to achieve. You've said you think users will get lost scrolling but the reality is we all scroll all day. Scrolling is never an issue. Good content to keep us in place and direct us is the larger issue.